# Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 113

Tags: mysql

Within my application I recently get the above error message. I did look into the internet for solutions but did not come up with anything yet. The base problem for it is that this error occurs approximately after 1000 database connections, so 1000 connections without a problem and then this error and so on.

Based on this fact all the problems regarding iptables, firewall etc. cannnot be a problem because normally everything works fine. Another valid point to mention that the error did started approximately two weeks ago without any change within the application / access / google crawl rate. Now the error is there and does not want to go away! ;)

Could that be an indicator of an hardware issue? What does system error 113 mean (cause I did find a lot of these problems with error code 111)? Is there any meaningful hint how I can reproduce / debug the error?

Best Regards

Ulf

Comment: How did you perform connection to mysql db? By IP or domain name? Error means *system error 113 == no route to host, check your sql server hostname as mtp suggested*

Comment: connection is established by using the ip (mysql pdo extension of php). but this works for 99% of the time so a mis-configuration does not make sense to me cause why should it work at all in general and just fail a couple of times?

Comment: Are you using `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT`?

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem to yours where i'd get this error in rare cases (usually caused by bots crawling the site)
Have a look at your MySQL server variables:

```
wait_timeout
max_connections
```

Limit the wait_timeout and/or increase the max_connections.

See: [max_connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections) and [wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout).